# Regular expression for Password match in PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have built a regular expression for password policy match, but it is not working as expected

/((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#\$%!])(?!(.)*\1{2,}).{6,20})/

`Password must satisfy below rules`
-> must have 1 digit
-> must have 1 upper case letter
-> must have 1 lower case letter
-> must have 1 special character from given list
-> minimum 6 character long
-> maximum 20 character long
-> Not more than 2 identical characters`

So it matches

aDm!n1, Adw1n@

but it must not match below 
aaaD!n1, teSt@111

I have searched for this regular expression and found "(?!(.)*\1{2,})" is not working properly

I am not getting why it is not working even though it has lookahead negative assertion.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Not more than 2 identical characters" --- this is a stupid rule. "maximum 20 character long" --- this is another stupid rule.

Comment: Don't go for all rules, I have added it for simplicity

Comment: So you intentionally added meaningful (and insecure) requirements? That's weird.

Comment: How it is insecure? there is no maximum character limit actually. It is to stop user entering passwords like 111@aaa.AAA

Comment: "there is no maximum character limit actually" --- `.{6,20}` --- 1. there is 2. It reduces the space of possible passwords significantly. Do you seriously think this is `ziMsp8DyQk3MXK3CDNOocsDOHHHH` an insecure password?

Answer (score 1):

You must need to provide start and end anchors.

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#\$%\!])(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1).{6,20}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cG7bP4/3)

To match the strings which isn't contain more than two duplicate characters, you need to use a negative lookahead like `(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1)` which asserts that the string we are going to match wouldn't contain not more than two duplicate characters.

- `(?!)` Negative lookahead which checks if there isn't
- `.*` Any character zero or more times.
- `(.)` A single character was captured.
- `.*` Any character zero or more times.
- `\1` Reference to the group index 1. That is, it refers to the character which are already captured by group 1.
- `.*` Any character zero or more times.
- `\1` Back-referencing to the character which was present inside the group index 1.

Code:

```
> var re = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#\$%\!])(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1).{6,20}$/;
undefined
> re.test('aDm!n1')
true
> re.test('Adw1n@')
true
> re.test('tetSt@11')
false
```

Comment: teSt@111 this is invalid as it contains 111 thrice. But it is still validated

Comment: @user1531437 now check my regex.

Comment: Still it is not working, gives "Your pattern does not match the subject string."

Comment: could you provide the subject string? If you don't want to allow the strings like `ftftT` (ie, there t's upper or lower case) then use a case insensitive modifier.

Comment: It must not allow same continuous character more than twice
abababab Allowed
aaaabbcc Not allowed
It has nothing to do with case, any character must be checcked

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#\$%!])(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1).{6,20})
```

You need this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/22

Your regex was failing cos

`(?!(.)*\1{2,})` will not work as it find consecutive repeated characters and not any character which is three times or more.So use `(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1)`.

```
var re = /^(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#\$%!])(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1).{6,20})$/gm;
var str = 'aaaD!n1\nteSt@111\naDm!n1\nAdw1n@';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```